# ADB issue while connecting through WiFi

Tags: adb

I am running adb port forwarding from computer to mobile with this command:

```
adb forward tcp:6401 tcp:50000
```

which is working completely fine (accessing 127.0.0.1) when I am accessing it through the same computer, but once I try to reach it through local WiFi (local IP 192.168.1.134) I am getting 'connection refused'. What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

First connect adb with usb then *make connection in same network*. Don't disconnect adb over usb. Now execute adb over tcp. If you are forwarding to some port means you have to disable firewall on that port. To disable firewall on port if you use linux. Open terminal or press `ctrl+alt+t`, Then try with these commands

```
ufw allow port_number
```

here replace this port number with forwarded new port number.

If you are windows user
[this](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-networking/how-do-i-disable-the-firewall-on-ports-2078-and/a9d7f7dc-e7e0-4dbb-bf25-d99649c4eaec) thread may helpful for you.
After allowing this port restart your adb server. Once the device is connected over wifi then you can remove your usb from your pc. If you need to know about port forwarding in adb see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18930050/adb-connection-over-tcp-not-working-now) thread.